# What is the django 1.7+ equivalent of south.signals.ran_migration?

Tags: django, django-migrations

South's "ran_migration" signal is fired after each, individual, migration file is run (as opposed to after an app's full migration is complete, which is the post_migrate signal).

Is there an equivalent to that signal in the built-in Django migrations?

Comment: There is no such signal in Django migrations. What do you need it for?

Comment: We have a signal that we want to fire the first time (and ONLY the first time) a certain app is set up.  We've been doing this, in the past, by detecting if/when the "0001_initial" migration ran, since that particular migration only runs once for the life of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not have a signal that runs after each separate migration.

You can add a [`RunPython`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython)  operation at the end of your initial migration, and run the function that used to receive the signal from there. This automatically ensures that it is only run at the end of the initial migration for that specific app.

Answer (score 0):

You could try subclassing [`MigrationRecorder`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c2e62fd1aed093c4d9ff84e3d86e6a85c8aa1917/django/db/migrations/recorder.py) and wrapping the `migrate` command to use your subclass as its migration recorder (the `recorder` property on `MigrationExecutor`, which you could override via subclass or monkey-patch as it is a "public" property). Then you can extend its behavior to do what you need.